# Why does the following conditional operator "?:" compile but give a run-time error

Tags: c#, conditional-expressions

I cannot figure out why the following program compiles without warnings, but in the exception block the conditional operator gives a NullReferenceException.

```
using System;

namespace Playground
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string message1 = "First message.";
            string message2 = null;
            // This works without a problem
            Console.WriteLine(message1 + message2 == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + message2);
            Console.ReadKey();

            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Now with an exception.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // This will give a NullReferenceException:
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.InnerException == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.Message);
                // ..But this will work:
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + (ex.InnerException == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know about the `??` operator, my question is about why the first line in the exception handler gives a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Atomosk *(Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.Message) should do the trick* If `ex.InnerException` is null, then the exception will still be thrown

Comment: The "But this will work:" line is massively different to the other line, I do hope you realise that. Besides `ex.Message + ex.InnerException == null` as your condition doesn't really make any sense. Here it is false when the innerException is null because "foo" + null = "foo"

Comment: Without parentheses it's equivalent to 'concatenate ex.Message with ex.InnerException.ToString(), then compare result with null'.

Comment: So why does `Console.WriteLine(message1 + message2 == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + message2);` work?

Comment: @Meine Concatenation with null is ok, calling `Message` of null is exception. Change `Environment.NewLine + message2` to `Environment.NewLine + message2.ToString()` and it will throw exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ex.Message + ex.InnerException
```

is converted into

```
string.Concat(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
```

this checks its arguments for null and only converts them to strings if they are not.
This means that

```
ex.Message + ex.InnerException == null
```

is `false` so the expression

```
Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.Message
```

is evaluated. This throws an exception since `ex.InnerException` is null.

Comment: _only converts them to strings if they are not._ no it doesn't. it adds an empty string for null values.

Comment: @Selman22 - Right, I mean it doesn't call `ToString` on them. `string.Empty` is the identity for string concatenation so there's no visible difference between doing nothing and concatenating `string.Empty`.

Comment: So why does `Console.WriteLine(message1 + message2 == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + message2);` work?

Comment: @Meine because  you are not trying to access any member of message2, even if it's null it just returns an empty string.

Comment: @Meine - The code in your question throws because you are trying to access the `Message` property of a `null` object. `string.Concat` is safe for null arguments, so `message1 + message2` is safe if `message1` or `message2` are null. If you tried to evaluate `message1.Length` in the else branch you would also get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

if `InnerException` is null but `ex.Message` isn't, then the first expression will evalute to `false` and will try to access `ex.InnerException.Message` which is giving you the `NullReferenceException`.

In the second expression you are trying to access `ex.InnerException.Message` **only** if the `ex.InnerException` is *not null* and that's why it works..

`NullReferenceException` occurs when you are trying to access a member (method, property, field etc.) of a null `object`.In your first example:

```
message1 + message2 == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + message2;
```

you are concatenating the new line with `message2` and you are not accessing any properties or methods on `message2`.It just adds an empty string for null values.Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `string.Concat`:

> The method concatenates str0 and str1; it does not add any delimiters.
>      An **Empty string** is used in place of any null argument.

If you write:

```
message1 + message2 == null ? "" : Environment.NewLine + message2.ToString();
```

Then you will get an exception.

Comment: I like this answer very much because it also addresses why the strings example does not throw an error. But @Lee's example addresses my question in a very clear manner, so I've marked his answer as the answer.